# check local user accounts for blank passwords

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, user-accounts

I need a tool/script that can help me find local user accounts that do not have passwords across a network. Not all computers will be on the domain, but 90% are (win2003). But I need to audit/check local user accounts, not domain user accounts.

Comment: You might think of rephrasing your question, after reading the faq http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: I was looking for more of a best practice recommendation, so I could not ask a specific question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7558) - Run, "Check for weak passwords", Start Scan...

Comment: does this have to be installed on each computer?

Comment: No, you only install it on an administrative workstation and run it from there.